# How could a service detect that an activity has closed?

Tags: android, android-service, android-activity, android-2.3-gingerbread

I have a service both of *started* and *bound* type (as defined [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html)). It is started to run indefinitely, then a separate application binds to it: when this application is destroyed, it calls the `unbindService` on its `onDestroy` method.

The service should detect that this application is finished. I read about [onUnbind](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onUnbind%28android.content.Intent%29) method, which is *called when all clients have disconnected from a particular interface published by the service*. However I need to know not when all clients are disconnected, but any disconnection. Is it possible?

I thought that, during the closing (inside the `onDestroy` method) the application could send a message to the service (taking advantage of the fact that the service is bound): later it should invoke the `unbindService` method, as follows.

```
// method of the application
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    service.closed();   // service is defined by IService.aidl
    unbindService(...);
}
```

In this way the application would send the last message to the service (`service.closed()` method) and then unbind the service. Could it work correctly? Does the `service.closed()` method return when the message arrived at its destination? Or could there be a risk that the message is not delivered due to the next call to `unbindService` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible?

Have the activity call a method on the `Binder` before unbinding to indicate that it is dropping the connection.

> Could it work correctly?

It should. AIDL calls are synchronous, so `unbindService()` will not occur until after the `Binder` has been called with `closed()`, in your sample.